# Encrypting a string in .net and decrypting it in python

Tags: c#, asp.net, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to encrypt password using system.Security.Cryptography which is working properly
This is the code (.Net)

```
if (clearText == null)
{
    clearText = "";
}
string EncryptionKey = "****";
byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
    encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
    encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
            cs.Close();
        }
        clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
return clearText;
```

And this is decryption code in python which is not working properly

```
def Decryptstr(self, text):
    try:
        EncryptionKey = "****"
        if text is None:
            return
        else:
            cipherbytes = base64.b64decode(text)
            salt = '\0x49\0x76\0x61\0x6e\0x20\0x4d\0x65\0x64\0x76\0x65\0x64\0x65\0x76'
            key_bytes = KDF.PBKDF2(EncryptionKey, salt, dkLen=32)
            iv = KDF.PBKDF2(EncryptionKey, salt,dkLen=16)
            cipher = AES.new(key_bytes, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
            password = cipher.decrypt(cipherbytes).decode('utf-16')
            print(password)
            return password
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

following is the output of the above code for the encrypted string ('eet123')
䏺꧴퐄妯৞軸힡薟

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In the C# code, how are you telling the `Aes` class that the mode is `CBC`? Or it is `CBC` by default?

Comment: by default the block cipher mode to use for encryption is CBC in c# @ikerbera

Comment: I think `.GetBytes()` returns the next n bytes. In that case your C# IV is bytes [32:48] while your Python IV is bytes [0:16] (which is also the first half of your key!). Also, Im not sure what is the defult hash algorithm in `KDF.PBKDF2`, but I think it's the same as `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` (SHA1).

Comment: hash algorithm is same for both KDF.PBKDF2 and Rfc2898DeriveBytes @t.m.adam

Comment: Good, but still the IV is incorrect as I explained above. Also, I think you should use `\x` to escape bytes - without the `0`.

Comment: Write a *complete* implementation in C# that round trips your unencrypted text. Then write *another* complete implementation in python that does the same thing. Try to decompose them into small chunks of functionality that do the same things in both. It's then a) a lot easier to compare outputs of stages and see where they disagree and b) easy to then introduce a point where one hands off the data to the other, satisfying your original requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that your `PBKDF2HMAC` key extraction in python side is incorrect. You need to pass correct parameters and get a 48 bytes key. Then use first 32 bytes as `Key` and last 16 bytes as `IV` (in your design).

Here is a working `C#`/`Python` code pair. First `C#` part:

```
static string encrypt(string clearText = "")
{
    if (clearText == null)
    {
        clearText = "";
    }

    string EncryptionKey = "****";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
       Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 }, 100000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1);
       encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
       encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
       encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
       using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
       {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
        clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return clearText;
}
```

About this `C#` code:

1. By default `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` uses `SHA1` and only 1000 rounds. My suggestion is that you should use at least 100,000. I have seen code apps that use 1,000,000 rounds. You can change hash too if you like, but number of rounds is more important.
2. Specify mode too. Even though it uses `CBC` by default, I think it is better to specify it.
3. Since `C#` uses key length to select `AES` algorithm, this code uses `AES-256`.

Now `Python` part:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

def Decryptstr(self, text):
    try:
        if text is None:
            return
        else:
            backend = default_backend()
            EncryptionKey = "****"
            salt = bytes([ 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 ])
            kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(algorithm=hashes.SHA1(),length=48,salt=salt,iterations=100000,backend=backend)
            key_bytes = kdf.derive(bytes(EncryptionKey, 'utf-8'))
            key = key_bytes[0:32]
            iv = key_bytes[32:]

            cipherbytes = base64.b64decode(text)
            cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
            password = cipher.decrypt(cipherbytes).decode('utf-8')
            print(password)
            return password
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

As you see, I used another `PBKDF2HMAC` library. I used it to create 48 bytes and used first 32 as `Key` and last 16 bytes as `IV`.

Comment: How do you make this url safe?